# Exception "Could not find image data or EI" using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a problem while parsing image from PDF file using iTextSharp, I am getting this exception: "Could not find image data or EI"

Code, where I am getting the exception:

```
var newFinder = parser.ProcessContent(lastPage, new ImageRenderListener());
var result = 0;
foreach (var key in newFinder.Images.Keys)
{
    result = key.Height;
}
return result;
```

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/50i5c51wzch75cn/test5.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Please supply sufficient detail so that people can attempt to help.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question itself. If there's too much, **reduce** it into a minimal example. Not many people are going to look at an external file.

Comment: Yup PDF broken. According to the spec. Image data should be `BI ... ID .. EI` with a newline before the EI. Missing newline at around byte offset 871982 just before the EI operator.

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp? There have been some fixes/improvements related to dealing with inline images. What I can think of immediately: [version 5.4.4](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/544) and [version 5.5.3](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/553). The Dropbox link to the sample file isn't working, so I can't check myself if parsing it works with the latest version.